# Unreal Engine 4, AddDynamic is not working if being called from constructor

Tags: unreal-engine4, unrealscript

I'm a begginer, trying to finish a simple **UE4** C++ tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/185-unreal-engine-4-c-tutorial#toc-anchor-001
At the point where you're additing `OnActorBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &ABaseCoin::OnOverlap)` into ABaseCoin constructor in order to handle the event, it's just not working. the **OnOverlap** function is not being called when I overlap this actor(
But if I put `OnActorBeginOverlap.AddDynamic` into `ABaseCoin::BeginPlay` everything is working.
Please, help, who knows something about this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems arise when using .AddDynamic in the constructor now. It can also cause Blueprint corruption.

Put every constructor .AddDynamic in PostInitializeComponents() or BeginPlay()

Comment: Thanks for replying!
PostInitializeComponents works for me!

Comment: it works, but it will result a error 'Ensure condition failed: InvocationList[ CurFunctionIndex ] != InDelegate' at every first load Level/Editor, but in game, it works fine.